# AngularJS logout not working with anonymous functions

Tags: angularjs

I am working on AngularJS 1.5 project where I have to clear some settings before logout()

Working code (which does not clear settings)

```
this.logout = userSession.logout
```

- userSession is a service which has logout

Modified code (which clears the settings but does not logout)

```
this.logout = () => {
    mySettings.clear()
    userSession.logout
}
```

Html Code:

```
<a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.logout()">
    <span class="icon-logout"</span>
</a>
```

Comment: (*stop editing it*) in your function you need to actually call the method, so change  `userSession.logout` to `userSession.logout()`, whereas before you were only referencing it

Comment: @AlekseySolovey It is working, Thanks, But I don't understand why it was working with `this.logout = userSession.logout` (without parentheses)

Comment: once again, you were referencing it. With that code `this.logout` became a method, which you can call using `this.logout()`, or in HTML: `$ctrl.logout()`

Comment: Ah understood, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the parentheses when calling userSession.logout.

Should be:

```
this.logout = () => {
    mySettings.clear()
    userSession.logout(); // added parentheses
}
```

Comment: It is working, Thanks, But I don't understand why it was working with `this.logout = userSession.logout` (without parentheses)